# Passing in $args variable to function

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-5.0

I have a script `tester.ps1`; the first thing it does is call a function (defined within the script itself) called `main`.

I need to pass in the automatic variable `$args` that was passed into *it* from the commandline.

How do I do this?

The following doesn't seem to work:

```
#Requires -Version 5.0
#scriptname: tester.ps1
function main($args) {
    Write-Host $args
}
# Entry point
main $args
```

When I save this `tester.ps1` and call it, the function doesn't see the passed-in parameter?

```
PS> . .\tester.ps1 hello world
From entry point: hello world
From Function:
```

Comment: Don't define `$args` as a param in your function: `function main {write-host $args }`

Comment: You can't use `$args` as an actual parameter; it's already a special value that always contains all the arguments to a function. In this case, simply making it `main()` is sufficient. (Passing `$args` to it is still required.) Saving `$args` outside the function in a global variable is another option, if you had many functions that needed access to all of them.

Comment: Thanks - but how then to 'stash' a copy of the $args as was set when I called the script. One reason to structure my script this way (with a 'main' function) was to try and avoid polluting variables back to the calling environment....

Comment: Got it: I just renamed my function params to 'my_args'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Jeroen Mostert's comment*; the solution is below.
Basically I was incorrectly trying to 'overload' or 'shadow' the built-in $arg variable.
I just need to have a param with a different name like this:

```
 #Requires -Version 5.0
    function main($my_args) {
        write-host "From Function:" $my_args 
    }
    # Entry point
    write-host "From entry point:" $args
    main $args

> . .\tester.ps1 hello world
From entry point: hello world
From Function: hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, simply removing `$args` from the `main` function declaration, would be enough to have the output you want.

Though, be aware that if you want to pass parameters by name, you need to call `main` with the splatting operator `@`, for example:

```
#Requires -Version 5.0
#scriptname: tester.ps1
function main($myString, $otherVar) {
    Write-Host $myString
}
# Entry point
Write-Host "Not using splatting: " -NoNewline
main $args

Write-Host "Using splatting: " -NoNewline
main @args
```

Output:

```
PS> . .\test.ps1 -myString "Hi World" -otherVar foobar
Not using splatting: -myString Hi World -otherVar foobar
Using splatting: Hi World
```

Find more about the splatting operator `@` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6)